# SQLite: Running balance with an ending balance

Tags: sqlite, accounting

I have an ending balance of $5000. I need to create a running balance, but adjust the first row to show the ending balance then sum the rest, so it will look like a bank statement. Here is what I have for the running balance but how can I adjust row 1 to not show a sum of the first row, but the ending balance instead.

```
with BalBefore as (
  select *
  from transactions
  where ACCT_NAME = 'Real Solutions'
  ORDER BY DATE DESC
)

select
  DATE,
  amount,
  '$' || printf("%.2f", sum(AMOUNT) over (order by ROW_ID)) as Balance
from BalBefore;
```

This gives me"

```
DATE         AMOUNT     BALANCE
9/6/2019     -31.00     $-31.00      <- I need this balance to be replaced with $5000 and have the rest
9/4/2019      15.00     $-16.00         sum as normal.
9/4/2019      15.00     $-1.00
9/3/2019     -16.00     $-17.00
```

I have read many other questions, but I couldn't find one that I could understand so I thought I would post a simpler question.

Comment: The easiest way is to simply have another row in your transactions table (as the first record), which contains the opening balance. Then, you would not have to change your sql statement. Another alternative is to add 5000 to the amount in your selection, but then the select statement would only be valid for this particular account.

Comment: Post your expected results.

Comment: Is there a way to just insert a row before the actual data that had an opening balance using a query. I had ```'$' || printf("%.2f", $5000 + sum(AMOUNT) over (order by ROW_ID)) as Balance ```, but that makes the opening balance 4069. Is there a way to get the amount of the first row? Then I could replace the code about with $5000-row1.amount, then the balance would be $5000. I have 10 accounts, but each report will be run separately by account.

Comment: Why don't you post the expected results to clarify what you want?

Comment: Should just need a `UNION ALL` in there somewhere if you don't want an actual initial row in the table.

Comment: I know the actual balance is $5000, but the first row is -31 because that is the actual result of the SUM(Amount). I need to make that rows balance (first row) start at 5000 instead of -31. It would still be an actual record, with the balance of 5000.

Comment: @RobertGriffinrealsol  I have a solution, but I think you need to clarify and/or correct your terminology and example data.  You use the term **beginning balance**, but the example data shows that the balance should be applied to the transaction with the **last date**.  This is not consistent with the idea of a "beginning" balance.  For the same reason, the data and query show values being added in the wrong date order.  Was all that intentional or is the entire query, question and example data mixed up? (DO NOT add all this in the comments.  You really need to edit and clean up the question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is not short and sweet, but using the [WITH statement and CTEs](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_with.html), I hope that the logic is apparent.  Multiple CTEs are defined which refer to each other to make the overall query more readable.  Altogether the goal was just to add a beginning balance record that could be :

```
/*
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS data;
CREATE temp TABLE data (
       id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
       date DATETIME  NOT NULL,
       amount NUMERIC NOT NULL
);   

INSERT INTO data
(date, amount)
VALUES
     ('2019-09-03', -16.00),
     ('2019-09-04',  15.00),
     ('2019-09-04',  15.00),
     ('2019-09-06', -31.00)
;
*/

WITH 
     initial_filter AS (
         SELECT id, date, amount
         FROM data
         --WHERE ACCT_NAME = 'Real Solutions'
     ),
     prepared AS (
         SELECT *
         FROM initial_filter
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 
            9223372036854775807 as id, --largest signed integer 
            (SELECT MAX(date) FROM initial_filter) AS FinalDate, 
            -(5000.00) --ending balance (negated for summing algorithm)
     ),
     running AS (
          SELECT
                id,
                date,
                amount,
                SUM(-amount) OVER 
                    (ORDER BY date DESC, id DESC 
                     RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
                     EXCLUDE CURRENT ROW) AS balance
          FROM prepared
          ORDER BY date DESC, id DESC
     )
SELECT *
FROM running
WHERE id != 9223372036854775807
ORDER BY date DESC, id DESC;
```

This produces the following

```
id  date         amount balance
4   2019-09-06  -31.00  5000
3   2019-09-04   15.00  5031
2   2019-09-04   15.00  5016
1   2019-09-03  -16.00  5001
```

UPDATE: The first query was not producing the correct balances.  The beginning balance row and the windowing function (i.e. OVER clause) were updated to accurately sum over the correct amounts.
*Note*:  The balance on each row is determined completely from the previous rows, not from the current row's amount, because this works backward from an *ending balance*, not forward from the previous row balance.

Comment: I changed my main question as it was worded wrong. It is the ending balance that is given to me, not the beginning balance. Thanks, C Perkins. Your statement is so convenient as I can adjust the last SELECT to even narrow down my results, like a date range, and your totals are spot on. I will be able to use this in many reports. Thanks again.

Comment: I am having problems with this code. If the first line (id 4) is an even number, it changes the entire amount column from a double to an integer column, thus nothing past the decimals.My results running the code above gives me -31,15,15,-16 in the Amount column. No decimales. But, if the first amount has a decimal amount, the column stays as a double.

Comment: Changing your code from a NUMERIC for the amount to REAL fixed the sample, but I am not sure how to do it when I am using a live database. My initial filter looks like this: `initial_filter AS (
         SELECT ROW_ID, DATE, AMOUNT, ACCT_NAME, DESCRIPTION, CATEGORY, NOTES
         FROM transactions
         WHERE ACCT_NAME = "Real Solutions"`, where the AMOUNT is a CURRENCY field. How can I get SQLite to honor the float throughout the SELECTS instead of basing the column type by the first amount in row 1?

Comment: If fixed the issue by changing the bottom `SELECT *` to `SELECT ROW_ID, DATE, ACCT_NAME, DESCRIPTION, CATEGORY, NOTES, cast(AMOUNT as REAL) as AMOUNT, BALANCE`. You should adjust your answer to casting the Amount as REAL.

Comment: There is no need to adjust the answer for the fact that the question was not language or tool specific.  It is only demonstrating a running balance technique in sqlite.  The entire point of such an answer is that you will tailor the details to your needs.

Comment: But even so, in your case it is important to understand details of [sqlite data types](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), namely that a column can be assigned a type affinity, but there is no strict data type for a column.  In fact, any value type can be stored in any column.  Sqlite itself will automatically store values based on the type affinity.  Intermediate numeric calculations will automatically handle conversion.  Even for a value where stored as an integer, if a calculation produces a decimal (a.k.a. float, numeric, double, currency), sqlite will automatically store it as such.

Comment: If you are experiencing inconsistent results between integers and float, there are a couple possibilities:  The tool that you are using may be formatting numbers dynamically, **formatting** integers and floats with zero decimals as basic integer values (i.e. 34.00 => 34).  This is simply a side affect of many management tools.  An actual user application should indicate a specific format.

Comment: The 2nd possibility is that whatever host language, api or 3rd-party tool that you are using is automagically selecting a data type based on the affinities and/or first value(s).  In that case, then it is up to you to either explicitly define data types for certain columns and/or perform the casts as you demonstrate to force (i.e. trick) the data model into using the desired type.  But you did not provide such details about your overall platform, nor what tools or code you are using, so that really is irrelevant to the answer and like I said before up to you to solve in your own situation.

Comment: Thanks for the help with this. I am using Delphi 10.3 and it's query component for the SQLite database must be setting the data types. My apologies.